# Characterization of Isogenous Elliptic Curves over Finite Fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am looking for a detailed proof (or a reference containing a detailed proof) of the following fact:

I know that $\mathbb F_p$-isogenous elliptic curves over $\mathbb F_p$ have the same number of $\mathbb F_p$-points. Is the converse true?

Comment: What's your definition of $\mathbb F_p$-isogeny? Surjective map with finite kernel? I ask because at this point, having the same characteristic polynomial (of frobenius) is what I take as a defintion.

Comment: I guess this note does it although it may be overkill for your purpose:
http://personal.psu.edu/mup17/Research/HTS.pdf. See Corollary 3.6

Comment: Great! I do not understand how semisimplicity gives 3 iff 4 and how G being topologically generated by Frobenius gives 2 iff 3 in the relevant corollary in that document.

Comment: The Tate modules are continuous G-representations so it’s enough to check equality on a dense subset which the powers of Frobenius provide. As for the semi simplicity argument, this result goes by the name of Brauer-Nesbitt which unfortunately also refers to some other results

Comment: Aha, I know Brauer-Nesbitt. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Arkady How do we get semisimplicity of Frobenius from the char poly? I didn't understand that part of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true but not obvious! It was proved by John Tate (1966) in his paper "[Endomorphisms  of  Abelian  Varieties  over  Finite  Fields](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/%7Efpazuki/index_fichiers/Tate66.pdf)", p. 139.

You can find the proof also in the book draft [here](http://gerard.vdgeer.net/AV.pdf), Corollary 16.25. (One just needs to use that if two elliptic curves over a finite field have the same number of points, then they have the same zeta function; it follows from the rationality and the functional equation of the zeta function: the numerator is just a polynomial $P(t) = 1 + a_1 t + ... + a_{2g} t^{2g}$ of degree $2g$ where $g=1$ being the genus of the curve, and such that $a_{2g-i} = q^{g-i} a_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq g$).